# Не получается присвоить null в Nullable C#

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Такой код не компилируется:

```
public static void f<T>()
{
    T? a = null;
}
```

Ошибка

```
Cannot convert 'null' to type parameter 'T' because it could be a value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: `T` структура или класс?

Comment: @aepot это generic параметр.

Comment: Что будет в обобщении, структура или класс? Для чего вам этот метод? Приведенный пример сам по себе смысла не имеет.

Comment: @ Вообще я работаю с классами. Но не очень понимаю какое это имеет значение. Смысл этого метода в том что-бы кратко изложить проблему. Если я скину сюда весь свой проект вряд-ли в нет будут разбираться. Если вам так важно могу придумать короткий осмысленный метод с такой-же проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вообще я работаю с классами

```
public static void f<T>() where T : class
{
    T a = null;
}
```

Либо

```
public static void f<T>()
{
    T? a = default;
}
```

Для ссылочных типов `default` это всегда `null`.

Кстати, для ссылочных типов `T?` это просто аннотация, по факту `string` и `string?` в рантайме одно и то же. Для значимых напротив `int?` это `Nullable<int>`, поэтому у компилятора крыша едет, если вы объявляете `T?` не применяя к нему никаких ограничений. Хотя, казалось бы, с точки зрения семантики языка должно быть всё логично.

Подробнее о всех нюансах можно почитать в документации: [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).